# Laravel 5 console handlers

Tags: php, console, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I like the philosophy of the Laravel 5 commands and their command handlers. Only I'm wondering why this isn't the same for console commands. Why put the logic in a console class while not creating a separate handler for it. So my question is, what is best practice for console classes. Why put the logic inside it? Or is there something I've missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing stopping you from extracting a command class from code within your console. That way you can call a specific command from either the console, or via HTTP.

It is purely dependent on your architecture.

Comment: Oke that's what I thought too. I just wanted to know what's best practice.